# how to save the output of a print statement

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, scipy, separator

i just want to save the output of  the print statement of each for loop to a text file named test.txt and inside the text file each for loop output should be separated with >>> symbol, plus  i want to put a header on the top of the text file as 'column-a'.The code i tried is below:

```
a = ['oof', 'rab', 'zab']
for i in range(1,5):
    for file in a:
        print('>>>')
        data=print(file)
with open(“test.txt”,w) as f: 
f.write(data)
```

by executing the above code i am getting out put like as below

```
oof
rab
zab
oof
rab
zab
oof
rab
zab
oof
rab
zab
```

but i need output like as below
test.txt

```
column-a
>>> 
oof
rab
zab
>>>
oof
rab
zab
>>>
oof
rab
zab
>>>
oof
rab
zab
```

I hope some solution i will get.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
In this case, what you literally ask is not possible: `print` output goes to `stdout`, which is a write-only channel.  Instead, you have to "echo", or repeat the output, writing it to a file.

Comment: @quamrana i just updated the q

Comment: @Prune i just updated my code which doesnot work

Comment: @quamrana i just upated my tried code....but doesnot work

Comment: As I said before, you cannot save what you `print`, yet you tried to do that.  Again, refer to the examples in your tutorial on writing to a file.

Comment: @Prune i am trying but unable to do...if u can help it would be better

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow. Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: You can try using a class has an attribute to store your data, and a `write` method, which appends the passed string to the data attribute. Create an instance, and pass it to `print`, using `print(your_stuff, file=your_instance)`.

Comment: @EdWard can you please show what you want to tell through my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` statement can be used to directly write into an open file with the `file` keyword argument:

```py
items = ['oof', 'rab', 'zab']

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:

    # header
    print('column-a', file=file)

    # loop with >>> separators
    for i in range(5):
        print('>>>', file=file)

        # print list items
        for item in items:
            print(item, file=file)
```

This code above creates a `file.txt` file with the content:

```
column-a
>>>
oof
rab
zab
>>>
oof
rab
zab
>>>
oof
rab
zab
>>>
oof
rab
zab
>>>
oof
rab
zab
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write to the file as well as printing to the screen.  Note that you also have UTF-8 "66 & 99" double quotes in your code, not simple `"` characters.

```
a = ['oof', 'rab', 'zab']
f = open( "test.txt", "wt" )
for i in range( 1, 5 ):
    for word in a:
        print( word )
        f.write( word + "\n" )
    print( '>>>' )
    f.write( '>>>' + "\n" )
f.close()
```

Comment: thank you very much....one thing still missing...i want to add  column-1 on the top of  the saved test.txt file followed by >>>